# Access Query Creation for Summation

Tags: ms-access-2010

so I have a question about sorting through my data, Lets say for argument sake I have multiple tables in access one for every month of the last 3 years so lets say 36 tables, each table has a Colum called pet and a column called name (A persons name). The pet can either be Cat, Dog, or Fish. I want to make a Cross Query that goes through each table finds all the different names of the people and then counts how many times that the pet has either "Cat", "Dog", or "Fish". I was wondering how to go about doing this, also is it possible to then drill down and find out if a person say Jane has 3 Cats and 2 Dogs, which tables the "Dog"'s come from and which tables the "Cat"'s come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would tackle something like this.

Create a view that joins all your tables together. The view will have the form of

```
SELECT "TB1" as TableName, name, pet
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT "TB2" as TableName, Name, pet
FROM Table2

UNION ALL ...
```

Continue unioning all the tables together. Then you can write your query against your view.

Something like

```
SELECT Name, Pet, Count(Pet), TableName
FROM View
Group BY Name, Pet, TableName
```

Let me add the observation that a design like this is going to be a maintenance  nightmare. It would be better to have everything it one table with a date column so that you don't have to join in multiple tables. Next month you will have to update your view to include the new table.